# Microsoft Mouse Without Borders: are data of the first pc private?

Tags: microsoft, microsoft-mouse-without-borders

I would like to use Microsoft Mouse Without Borders to **share the mouse and keyboard of my workstation with my personal tablet** (basically, I need an extra monitor to write work notes while I am using the working tools in the main monitor).

My workstation contains **high confidential client data**, that are managed both **locally and on cloud** (One Drive), and it is a priority that this data remains private and is not read from the personal tablet, and there is not the slightest possibility that this privacy will be put at risk.
Given such a priority:

- Is it unsafe to share the mouse and keyboard of my workstation with
  Microsoft Mouse w/o borders?
- If there is a security problem or malware on my personal tablet and a
  hacker is able to read the data, would he also be able to read the
  data on my workstation if I'm sharing my mouse and keyboard?

Basically, is the second computer with which to share the mouse and keyboard capable of reading the traffic of the first?

Comment: Unless you work for Microsoft, once you put your client data on One Drive it’s not confidential anymore.